# errors attempting to start Apache through XAMPP

Tags: apache, service, path, installation, xampp

This is what shows up when I attempt to run Apache without Apache service being activated:

```
>Status change detected: running
>Status change detected: stopped
>Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
>and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

This is what happens when I attempt to install the Apache service:

```
>Installing service...
>Apache Service detected with wrong path
>Change XAMPP Apache settings or
>Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager
>Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k run service
>Successful!
```

...followed by attempting to start Apache after the service (failed) attempt:

```
>Attempting to start Apache service...
>System Error.  Code: 5.
>Access is denied
```

Does anyone know what's going on here and/or are able to help troubleshoot?

I've already uninstalled and reinstalled with and without (zip file extraction) the installer.

Comment: Turn off IIS if you have that running.

Comment: IIS does not appear to be running under Services.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like something may be running on port 80 already. What happens when you run

```
netstat -an |find /i "listening"
```

from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I had those messages as well. You probably have IIS and XAMPP clashing at port 80. You can either:

- disable IIS (if you are not going to run the server regularly).
- change XAMPP default ports.
- change IIS default ports.

**To change XAMPP default ports**

Open your ***XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf*** file and change the "**80**" ports to something else, people like "**8080**".

Open your ***XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf*** file and change the "**443**" ports to another number. 
It should make both services run without conflicts.